# How do I remove/modify axis titles on charts on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I am drawing charts from pandas dataframe but can't get to remove the textbox above the chart that says "camis" nor do i manage to change the various axis labels. How could I do so?

I have tried to modify all of the functions arguments and looked everywhere on this forum but nothing will delete the textbox or change/add the y axis labels.

I am using the following code:

`plot2df = df.groupby("food")["camis"].count() / df_cleaned.groupby("food")["camis"].count()
plot2df.plot(kind="bar",subplots = True, figsize=(4,4),ylim = (0.5,1))`

Attached is the image too [image: chart]

Answer (score 0):

The df.plot() function returns a `matplotlib` object. You can set the axis titles on that object.

```
plot = plot2df.plot(kind="bar", subplots=True, figsize=(4, 4), ylim=(0.5, 1))
plot.set(xlabel="x axis title", ylabel="y axis title")
plot.show()
```

The main title for the plot can also be added in the `df.plot()` funtion with the 'title' argument:

```
plot2df.plot(kind="bar", subplots=True, figsize=(4, 4),
             ylim=(0.5, 1), title="Add your title")
```